# Spring boot "@ConditionalOnProperty(value =)" injecting literal String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, properties-file

I have a Spring Boot application, with a class annotated as a `@RestController` and also having `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on my class `MyRestController.kt` (kotlin) as below:

```kotlin
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = ["app.running-mode.read-write"],havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)

class MyRestController(private val r : MyRestService){
    @GetMapping
    // some endpoint here
    
    @PostMapping
    // some endpoint here
}
```

My `application.properties` looks like this:

```
app.running-mode.read-write=${MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE}
```

When I run my app sometimes, it crashes for a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` on my class that contains this `ConditionalOnProperty` annotation `MyRestController.kt`, and I see it says:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE` in value "${MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE}"
```

This should be an environment variable set by Azure, but do I possibly have my `@ConditionalOnProperty` defined incorrectly such that it is injecting the literal String, as seen in the logs, instead of the environment variable? (Which should be a boolean `true` or `false`, by the way)

Comment: May be `MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE`  is being set in environment after application has started.

Comment: It seems correct what you are doing. 

But in the controller you are forgiviing if the variable is not set. So in your application.properties you could also add a default value.
app.running-mode.read-write=${MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE:defaultValue}
Then if the environment vairable is not set the application will still start and perhaps you could use a shell or something to log into the image you run it on and see if the variable is there or not?

Comment: @Smile I logged onto the cloud server at the `MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE` variable is indeed there. The app, which is just a WAR file, is currently crashed and won't deploy , because it keeps throwing that same java.lang. exception I listed above, as if its injecting the literal string.

Comment: @Ole Billie, if it's truly injecting the environment variable and not some String, then I should be able to run this locally , and just set an envrionment variable in Windows like `MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE=true` then the properties file should pick it up, yes? i.e app.running-mode.read-write=${MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE}

Well, the problem is , this NEVER works locally unless I hardcore the value in the .properties (either a true or false)...so it's injecting just the literal String of "${MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE}" isn't it.....

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not matching the property name and the environment-variable name, since they're already so close?

Comment: Just tried it again. I use intellij idea and I run the spring boot application in debug mode. If I add the environment variable from commandline with set.... then its not included and I get the error you are getting. But if I add it as an evironment variable in the configuration in "Run/debug configuration" then it works like a charm.

Comment: @Ole Billie, you have to restart your intelij after you add environment variables though, did you do that? if you have the same intellij window open and add the variable, and try, it won't work....

Answer (score 2):

The issue could arise from how you have provided the value. Since you are injecting the value from environment for the different env, it's possible that the value may not be present or even provided wrongly in the environment. Check to veirfy that it's provided correctly. Make sure that the environment is configured with the key "MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE".

Since you are reading the value from `application.properties` then try providing it like below after removing '[]' :

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.running-mode.read-write",havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)

class MyRestController(private val r : MyRestService){
    @GetMapping
    // some endpoint here
    
    @PostMapping
    // some endpoint here
}
```

Comment: yes, I am deploying to Azure cloud actually, and I logged onto their remote server and verified the environment variable `MY_API_RUNNING_MODE_READ_WRITE` was indeed there. I even re-deployed my app and it still failed, which made me think it has nothing to do with the environment variable being there or not.

Comment: @ennthare you deploying a spring boot docker image on your azure instance ? How are the environment variables getting set, is it configured to run before the deployment.?